# "In their thousands" and "in the thousands"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

Do they mean the exact same thing? Any nuances?

To borrow the Macmillan Dictionary's example:

> Londoners came out on the streets **in their thousands**.

may well be phrased as

> Londoners came out on the streets **in the thousands**.

Right?

Comment: **their** implies a solidarity amongst the Londoners or perhaps an emotional distance between the speaker and his subject. More context is needed.

Answer (score 2):

`in their thousands` can mean a grouping of people, implying that they all came out for the same purpose.  It can also mean a grouping as compared to other groups, i.e.,

> The Londoners came out in their thousands, the Berliners in their millions, but the aliens came in their billions, and overwhelmed them.

The phrase `in the thousands` is specifically specifying quantity.  Perhaps there is a cause for them to be numbered together, but their following actions may be different.  E.g.,

> The Londoners came out in the thousands.  Some came out to escape the heat of their top-floor flats, while others came to observe narrowly the tawdry parade going before them.  The children, of course, came out for the hard candies thrown out the sides of the colorful carriages.

Answer (score 0):

It's written *in **their** thousands* because there are *thousands **of them***.

*In **the** thousands* describes the number, not the people. You could say *The Londoners who came out **numbered in the thousands***, meaning more-or-less *at least a couple of thousands* and (probably) *less than a million*. An awkward one; how do you describe *one* thousand, or *a million*?

A valid (**in this context**) alternative is to say *Londoners **by the thousand**…* although the literal meaning of this is that they appeared in groups of a thousand.

Answer (score -1):

The danger of the former is that "in their XXs" can be taken as an indication of age, though we'd expect this to be more directly attached to the Londoners. Also by saying thousands (as opposed to e.g. 50s) it is fairly safe that age isn't really meant, but could cause potential confusion otherwise.

Agree with Tyaoshauo that "their" does add solidarity.

Comment: I'm sorry, I took the second sentence to refer to OP's second option (in the thousands).

Comment: No problem :) Mine's hardly an answer worth much of a defence.