# What does "range in millions" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm playing a video game called "Doom Ethernal" and there is some cataclysmic event on earth going on and a news anchor on tv says "human casualties **range in** millions"

"**Range**" def:

1. To vary within specified limits: *sizes that range from small to extra large*.(source thefreedictionary)

Does this mean that the casualties are in millions but it can be anything between million and many millions?

Comment: The short answer to your question is yes.

Answer (score 1):

As @Lambie correctly points out, the short answer is **yes**.

### To range

To *range* over something is to take an arbitrary value (or to vary) within it. Usually, we talk about something *ranging from A to B* where A and B are numbers. But you can *range* over anything that has its limits set out, and you don't always need two values to describe a limit. Some limits only require one descriptor (over the entirety of europe, the integers), some require two (between 0 and 1, between one hundred and one billion), some require three (the region from greece to italy to egypt), some require more.  Some examples:

> (*Range described by one descriptor*) 
> If *x* and *y* range over the integers, then either *x* > *y*, *y* < *x* or *x* = *y*. 
> We've gotten views from users whose IPs range over the entirety of Europe 
> \

### Millions

It is relatively common in English to describe the ranges 10-99, 100-999, 1,000-1,000, 10,000-99,999, 1,000,000-9,999,999 as *tens*, *hundreds*, *thousands*, *tens of thousands*, and *millions*. In general, any quantity ending in a 0 can be treated this way. We hear this pretty commonly when talking about ages: e.g. I'm in my *twenties*.

> (*Range described as between two descriptors*) 
> Recent estimates range from one thousand to over one million 
> The suspect's possible locations range from New York to Los Angeles 
>
> (*Range described by more than two descriptors*) 
> His boat's built-in GPS has given readings which range from Bermuda to Florida to Kazakhstan. It must be broken.

In this case ***millions* means "Somewhere between one million and ten million**

[This answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/158627/in-their-thousands-and-in-the-thousands) discusses the same topic.